# Bootstrap 3 Tooltip behave wierd when trigger is 'click' and not working when 'manual'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm getting crazy, I try to understood Tooltip behaviour but unsuccessfully.

**1.** The first issue is when I try to use it in on click event by plugin (button 1) -> if you will go to Fiddle than you will see that function inside of 'content' property is called twice every click... why?

**2.** I want to use Tooltip bound to an element (button 2) and show it in `manual` mode but then it's not working at all... why?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <br/>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">I'm working! :-D</a>   <span class="badge b0">0</span>         
            <br/>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <br/>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">I'm not working! :-(</a>   <span class="badge b1">0</span>         
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 var i = 0, j = 0; 

 $('.container').popover({
        selector: '.btn-success',
        html: true,
        placement: 'right',
        container: '.container',
        trigger: 'click',            
        content: function(){
            $('.badge.b0').text(j++);
            return 'test';
        }
  });

  $('.container').popover({
        selector: '.btn-danger',
        html: true,
        placement: 'right',
        container: '.container',
        trigger: 'manual',            
        content: 'test'
  });

  $('.container').on('click', '.btn-danger', function(){
        $('.badge.b1').text(i++);
        $(this).popover('show');            
  });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gepbmonh/5/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gepbmonh/6/

Comment: It works but what if I want to bound this tooltip to dynamically created elements? I already know solution but I tried to understand why it's not working in the way which I made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gepbmonh/8/

```
$('#add').click(function () {
     addButton()
 })

var ind = 0;
// adding buttons
function addButton() {
     ind++;
     // creating button
     $button = $('<a href="#"></a>');
     $button.text('I\'m not working! :-( ' + ind);
     $button.addClass('btn btn-danger has_popover');
     $button.attr('data-html', 'true');
     $button.attr('data-placement', 'left');
     $button.attr('data-trigger', 'manual');
     $button.attr('data-content', 'test ' + ind);
     // creating badge  
     $span = $('<span class="badge b' + ind + '">0</span>');

     $wrap = $('<div></div>');   
     $wrap.append($button).append($span);

     // add to the stage
     $('#buttons').append($wrap);
}
//inclick event
$('.container').on('click', '.has_popover', function () {
     // find an appropriately badge
     $badge = $(this).parent().find('.badge');
     // get current value
     var i = $badge.text();
     i = parseInt(i);
     // increase for one
     i++;
     $badge.text(i);
     //showing popover
     $(this).popover('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It isn't called twice every click, it is called once every click, but it is also counting the click that makes it go away, just the text only updates every other click.

2) I'm not really sure what you mean by this, could you explain further and I will edit my post.

Comment: Ad 2. - I need to get popover content via AJAX request and I don't want to get this data by sync AJAX call inside of popover content. I try to do it inside of success state of async AJAX by passing popover content to data attr and then show popover manually by use 'popover('show')' but it's not working. I tried to simplify my code and show popover manualy after bind it to element.